# Starting Process in Background without terminal does not work

Tags: command-line

I want to start the modelsim programm for linux with a *.desktop file. First I start the program with the script in the installation folder:

```
./vsim
```

and it is starting. There are a messages on stdout:

```
 Reading pref.tcl
```

Ok. I want to create a startet in `/usr/local/bin` and call it "modelsim". Typing now in a terminal `modelsim` it does start, but printing out the message. So I changed the program-calling in the "modelsim" script:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  /part/to/installation/vsim >> /dev/null &
```

I tried it with `&` and without, with `>> /dev/null` and without, but I never can start the programm out of my Desktop(XFCE4) with an desktop entry...(there are also no entries in the programm list). How to start this correctly?

Comment: I can't get your question. So you want to create a .desktop file to run modelsim? Please give more details.

Comment: the problem is(a shorter and better version): the programm should start "in the background", so if I type at the terminal: `modelsim`, the programm should start without blocking the same terminal, and the programm should start. But that don't work...

Comment: I wonder why that is really needed, but why don't you create a .desktop file? It's easier than the terminal.

Comment: The problem is: If I create a .desktop file with `Exec = /part/to/installation/vsim` it does not start

Comment: Simply set exec=modelsim, if `modelsim` works at terminal, it will work in a .desktop file too.

Comment: no, thats the problem I want to explain :( but if I add `Terminal=True` at the .desktop file, it start together with a terminal as stdout...

Comment: I didn't understand your real doubt, but you don't need to set terminal=true.

Comment: Ok. I've tried only `exec=modelsim` to the .desktop file(also `terminal=false`. When I type into terminal `modelsim` it starts. When I click on my desktop entry, it doesn't. Thats the problem why I ask this question.

Comment: Run `whereis modelsim` in a terminal. If `whereis is not installed` install it with `sudo apt-get install whereis`.

Comment: Then come back with the output of whereis.

Comment: `me@me:~$ whereis modelsim
modelsim:/usr/local/bin/modelsim`

Comment: then set exec=/usr/local/bin/modelsim and erase terminal= (It's set as false by default).

Comment: yeah, I also do that. And, like I wrote, it does not work. Thats the question. Why it does not work...

Comment: Please insert here the content of your dekstop file.

Comment: If you want to redirect command line output , you really need `>` not `>>`. Although idea is same, I've never seen that used. If you still see messages with `>`, this must be stderr stream, which you can redirect with `2>/dev/null`.  Try `nohup modelsim 2>&1 /dev/null` . If that does work, you can create an alias to this command, run it in terminal, and then close the terminal.